# How to achieve Player result mapping?

Tags: python

Given the following input :

```py
results = [
    {'WP': 'A', 'BP': 'B', 'result': '2-0'},
    {'WP': 'C', 'BP': 'A', 'result': '1/2-1/2'},
]
```

How to achieve the following output in python?

```py
{
    'A': [
        ('B',2.0),
        ('C',0.5)
    ],'B': [
        ('A',0.0)],
        'C':[('A',0.5)
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I took was finding all players first, creating the opponent-own score tuple list, and checking to see if "1/2" as float will not convert it. The adding it to a dictionary. Should work for more games, kind of long.

```
results = [{'WP': 'A','BP': 'B', 'result': '2-0'}, {'WP':'C', 'BP': 'A', 'result': '1/2-1/2'}]

def output(res):
    p = []
    for i in res:
        if (i['WP'] not in p):
            p.append(i['WP'])
            if (i['BP'] not in p):
                p.append(i['BP'])

    out_dic = {}
    for j in p:
        oppo = []
        for m in res:
            if m['WP'] == j:
                num = m['result'].split("-")[0]
                if num == "1/2":
                    num = "0.5"
                oppo.append((m['BP'], float(num)))
            elif m['BP'] == j:
                num = m['result'].split("-")[1]
                if num == "1/2":
                    num = "0.5"
                oppo.append((m['WP'], float(num)))
        out_dic[j] = oppo
    return out_dic
print(output(results))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do the trick

```
output = {}
for game in results:
  output.setdefault(game['WP'], []).append(game['BP']:float(game['result'].split("-")[0]))
  output.setdefault(game['BP'], []).append(game['WP']:float(game['result'].split("-")[1]))
```

the `setdefault` will either create the key if it's missing and append the results to it

`float(game['result'].split("-")[0])` separates the results by the dash then picks the first or second value and converts the string to a float